# Validating files in C

Tags: c

I need to validate load files for a game I'm making and I'm having troubles with it:

I just need to know if the first character is an int in some range, if the next one is an unsigned short int (checking the type and value of each character), and I couldn't find a function for this.

Also, I need to check if the n-th character is the last character in the file (return some error code if it is not).

The file is binary type.

How could I resolve this?

Thanks!

E:

This is my load file function:

```
Cod_Error load(Info * gameInfo)
{
    FILE * loadFile;
    unsigned short int dif;
    int i;


    randomizeSeed();

    gameInfo ->undo = FALSE;

    loadFile = fopen(gameInfo->fileArchivo, "rb");


    fread(&dif, sizeof(dif), 1, loadFile);

    gameInfo->size = sizeFromDif(dif);
    gameInfo->undoPossible = FALSE;

    gameInfo->board = newBoard(gameInfo->size);
    if(gameInfo->board == NULL)
        return ERROR_MEM;

    fread(&(gameInfo->score), sizeof(Score), 1, loadFile);

    fread(&(gameInfo->undos), sizeof(unsigned short int), 1, loadFile);

    for(i = 0; i < gameInfo->size; i++)
        fread(gameInfo->board[i], sizeof(Tile), gameInfo->size, loadFile);

    fclose(loadFile);

    return OK;
}
```

Comment: you could use some checksum to validate it, for example CRC, MD5 or SHA1 maybe, wouldn't it be suffiecient enough instead of checking some numbers in binary files?

Comment: Please show what you've tried. This is basic file IO so shouldn't be hard when making games.

Comment: @rsz That doesn't help if for some random reason you get a file in the wrong format but with a correct checksum.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't learned what checksums are yet, I'm just learning C.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen it depends, what part is necessary, because for binary types the checksums should be more than enough
//YoTengoUnLCD well, you will have to implement it yourself, read the file or the first x bytes and then check the chars

Comment: first write a program to read in the file, second check the buffer that came back. learning is solving one problem at a time, sometimes the next one requires a little research.

Comment: You tried simply reading the first however many bytes that is in the file and just applying simple comparison to these?

Comment: I added my load version, maybe that helps. @Magisch could you elaborate? As I've said, I'm a begginer at c and don't really know much about file managing...

Comment: You know how to read in portions from binary files right? If not you should probably mesh through a C book someday. If you know this, simply scan the first X bytes you want (sizeof int + sizeof unsigned short) and compare them to your liking.

Comment: What happens if I read the first 4 bytes of the file, expecting an int and there's actually a double there, or any type incompatibility, how do I handle that?

Comment: @rsz: None of them are checksums. A CRC is the remainder of a polynomial division, MD5 and SHA1 are hashes. While the former serves a similar purpose of a checksum, the latter two have other properties.

Comment: You read raw bytes from the file. Whether these represent an `int`, `float` or `char[4]` is specified by the program that reads the data. You can't read 4 bytes and say "Oh, they are a float".

Comment: You can't tell. Binary data is just that, binary. Wether or not 0110 is 6 in decimal or something entirely different in an any arbitrary encoding is detected by the program reading it, not by the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: You can't.

Long Answer:

In a binary file, there is no specification for what the binary data represents. That specification has to come from the developer of the program reading the file. For instance, lets take 2 bytes from an arbitrary file.

> 00101101 00110111

Now, what that is is entirely dependant on the program reading these bytes. You can try to read it as an int, and check if it makes sense (i.E is within a certain range) if interpreted as an int, and you can do the same for any other combination of binary data with any other data type. But you decidedly cannot tell what data type was used for writing it into the file, as now its just binary.

To quote @M.Oehm:

> You can't read 4 bytes and say "Oh, they are a float".

You can say however,

> "If I count these as a float, are they within a specified range I
>   set?"

Comment: I understand, I was hoping some type of `typeof(x)` function existed for this application.  If I understand correctly, that last part is my best chance at validating a file (and also, checking that the file has the correct length(e.g 4xInts+64*unsigned short ints)). However, there's always a chance for failure, right (reading a float as an int, and it getting in the right range)?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD A binary file is literally just that, a serial chain of 0s and 1s in memory. There is no type descriptor and no way to tell what kind of variable the bytes in a binary file are supposed to represent.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD And yes, thats always possible. Quite likely, even, for comparisons between ints and other forms of number storage. But it shouldn't be a concern in your case. If a binary combination reads as a valid int in a valid range, it might aswell be.